# distinguish between mobile layout vs desktop layout via jquery

Tags: html, css

I have to implement a feature in a responsive web page that should behave slightly differently depending on viewing it via mobile layout vs desktop layout.

Its a simple block with ul li items. On mobile layout I want to apply jquery hover to highlight the li items. On desktop layout, I want to be able to style the li items in a different manner.

I'm looking for a best approach to distinguish if the screen size is of mobile layout or if the size is of desktop layout. The approach i have in mind is

via media queries hide or show the class and then check for the presence of a class to distinguish between mobile vs desktop. Are there better approaches?

Note: Via media queries I'm showing different layouts but the problem is only specific to showing different behavior via jquery depending on the layout.

Comment: Why do you need to check for the presence of a class?  Why not just use the media queries to apply the difference between 'desktop' and 'mobile' styles?

Comment: I want to show different behavior via jquery if its mobile or desktop.

Comment: Simply display / hide different elements and bind functionality to that.

Comment: @LukePeterson - it's a good suggestion but I definitely have to say, -1, not enough JQuery. :)

Comment: Agree with Nit. Just provide .mobile / .desktop classes to your elements and bind your javascript selectors to elements that reside within those classes. Then you can use your media queries and Javascript in tandem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicate your [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) using logical operators, comparing body width against known sizes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var bodyWidth = $('body').width(); 

    if(bodyWidth > 320 && bodyWidth < 400) {
        alert('Mobile')   
    }

    if(bodyWidth > 768 && bodyWidth < 1024) {
        alert('Tablet')   
    }

    if(bodyWidth > 1224) {
        alert('Desktop')   
    }

});
```

You can also attach to the [`resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event for a more responsive effect.